# CameraX PreviewView showing nothing

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I followed these tutorials: 
https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview, 
https://proandroiddev.com/update-android-camerax-4a44c3e4cdcc 
First time I ran app the preview worked, but after I rotated screen all broke. I reinstalled app, but the preview doesn't work anymore

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;

private PreviewView cameraView;
private Preview imagePreview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    cameraView = findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
    cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
    if(isPermissionsGranted()){
        cameraView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startCamera();
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ScanActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

private void startCamera(){
  imagePreview = new Preview.Builder()
           .setTargetRotation(cameraView.getDisplay().getRotation())
           .build();
  imagePreview.setSurfaceProvider(cameraView.getPreviewSurfaceProvider());
  final CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                            .build();
  cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
      try {
          ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
          cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ScanActivity.this,cameraSelector,imagePreview);
      } catch (ExecutionException|InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  },ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));

}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A use case shouldn't be built before the camera is initialized, which is what `ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance()` does asynchronously. So what you may be running into is the Preview use case being built before the initialization is done, which is why the preview doesn't work. Your code should instead look like this.

```
cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
    try {
        ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get(context);
        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());   
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, selector, preview);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context));
```

Comment: How can I create custom Ui for CameraX perivew as barcode UI ?